# If statement javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

My if statement dont work. can someone help me by telling howe to check if my a.style.background is equal to my url open.png? i have the next code.

html

```
<a id="mnav" href="#" onclick="nav()" onmouseover="change()" onmouseout="back()"></a>
```

javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById('mnav')
    if(a.style.backgroundImage == "url(open.png)"){
            alert("help");
            a.style.backgroundImage="url(navopen.png)";
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english:)

https://jsfiddle.net/z8tz02hg/

Comment: what happens when you run `console.log(a.style.backgroundImage);`

Comment: show the HTML of `a` tag

Comment: Try using toLowerCase() on backgroundImage... Also, make sure that your images are in the folder you're referencing.

Comment: @taylorc93 if I use console.log it say: TypeError: open.console is undefined

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see the issue

Comment: @sam here is my link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z8tz02hg/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```html
if(a.style.backgroundImage.indexOf('url("open.png")') >= 0){
    alert("help");
    a.style.backgroundImage='url("navopen.png")';
}
```